# Computer connected to HDMI TV x RGB TV

Tags: mac, hdmi

I have bought today a 40 inch 1920x1080 TV that has several inputs as RGB, HDMI, etc.

My idea is to use this TV as my computer monitor. I am already using it but I am connected right now using the VGA port of my computer.

As my computer (Mac) has a DVI output for a secondary monitor, I am about to buy a DVI > HDMI adapter.

Right now the TV says that it is using 1920x1080 @ 60 Hz. The TV is capable of going up to 100 Hz.

My question is: What kind of improvement will I see connecting the TV to the computer using HDMI, instead of VGA? Will it be sharper? Will I be able to increase the refresh frequency to at least 75 Hz?

I am not sure if my Mac can go up to 75 Hz at this resolution (it says it is an iMac 7.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get a sharper, clearer image using HDMI/DVI rather than VGA.

As I'm not a native/often Mac user, I can't speak for maximum refresh rates, **but it's most likely up to the TV's max rate/different settings** rather than the computer's.  Depending on the model, your TV may only be able to do 60Hz through the HDMI port.